# MySQL JDBC driver incorrectly reports bigint as BigInteger when returning generated keys

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm dealing with a frustrating problem. MySQL (like most SQL databases) does not call its 64-bit integer datatype a "long". It's a "bigint". Ok, fine.

But the MySQL JDBC driver (8.0.22) incorrectly returns this column as java.math.BigInteger, which it isn't.

Yes, I could convert the BigInteger into a long in my application code, but this turns out to be really inconvenient for some internal, application-specific reasons.

Is there any way to force the driver to return the correct data type, which should be a java.lang.Long?

**Update**

Per the comment, yes, it appears that regular select statements do return the column as a java.lang.Long. My bad.

Where it is failing is when it returns generated keys after an insert. There, the column comes back as a BigInteger. Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    Connection conn = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&user=root");

    Statement state = conn.createStatement();
    state.executeUpdate("drop table if exists foo");
    state.executeUpdate("create table foo (id bigint auto_increment, name varchar(255), primary key(id))");
    state.executeUpdate("insert into foo (name) values ('bob')", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

    ResultSet rs = state.getGeneratedKeys();
    rs.next();

    Object obj = rs.getObject(1);

    System.out.println(obj);
    System.out.println(obj.getClass());

    conn.close();

}
```

returns:

```
1
class java.math.BigInteger
```

Comment: Is the MySQL column defined as `BIGINT` or `BIGINT UNSIGNED`? According to table 6.2 on [this documentation page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html), that determines the Java type (it will be a `Long`, unless you are using `UNSIGNED` - in which case it will be a `BigInteger`).

Comment: @andrewjames It's a bug then. I'm creating the column as "bigint autoincrement". Perhaps the autoincrement is forcing it to be unsigned, which it should not.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem. With a `BIGINT(20)` with autoincrement, but not unsigned, I am getting a Java `Long` from `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnClassName()`. Can you show more context in your question - or maybe a [mre]?

Comment: @andrewjames Example added. The problem appears to confined to returning a generated key. My error.

Comment: Now I can recreate the behavior, thank you - but I cannot explain it, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you simply use `Long autoValue = rs.getLong(1);` instead of `Object obj = rs.getObject(1);`, here? That returns the correct value and Java type. (Again, doesn't explain why you get `BigDecimal` from the object...)

Comment: This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Reported here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101823

Comment: Seems like this is not limited to `bigint` columns. I have a similar issue with an auto-generated key of type `int` resulting in JDBC returning an instance of a `BigInteger`. (There is no mapping of `int` to `BigInteger` listed in table 6.2. of the documentation linked to by @andrewjames)

Answer (score 2):

The underlying problem is, in the `getGeneratedKeys()` method, it makes no attempt to determine the column's type and instead hardcodes it as `MysqlType.BIGINT_UNSIGNED`, which equates to `BigInteger`.

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/1de2fe873fe26189564c030a343885011412976a/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/StatementImpl.java#L1389

> ```
> fields[0] = new Field("", "GENERATED_KEY", collationIndex, encoding, MysqlType.BIGINT_UNSIGNED, 20);
> ```

According to MySQL, they can't/won't fix this (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101823#c527721):

> The information regarding generated keys is not directly related to the table primary key in the sense that it does not share the same metadata rules. MySQL protocol indicates what has the last insert-id of the executed query independently of how many ids were actually generated and this information is not directly linked to any column in particular (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/page_protocol_basic_ok_packet.html), as such, Connector/J has no alternative other than using the most comprehensive data type in the generated keys result set. Also note that the spec does not make any assumptions regarding the columns or types to return in this result set (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys--) - for MySQL Connector/J it is BIGINT_UNSIGNED.

It seems like they could at least clarify the documentation on this method, since it's unintuitive and undiscoverable without digging through the source, but by their reasoning it's correct since, "the spec does not make any assumptions regarding the columns or types".

So the short answer is, unfortunately: there isn't a way to automatically get the appropriate type for a generated key. A specific method, like `getLong(1)`, needs to be used instead.